# how to set default value 0 to rails combo box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following select html element

```
<%= select_tag post, options_for_select(my_helper(param_to_generate_option)) %>
```

It will generate

```
<option value="1">test</option>
<option value="2">test1</option>
```

But how can i add

```
<option>select</option>
<option value="1">test</option>
    <option value="2">test1</option>
```

So that i can perform some valiation operation. I tried something like this

`options_for_select(['select', 0],my_helper(param_to_generate_option))`

But it is generating

select
0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `prompt` option.

```
select_tag post, options_for_select(my_helper(param_to_generate_option)), prompt: "Select something"
```

See the [`select_tag` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

Edit:  If you need a value use `include_blank` instead.  Something like:

```
select_tag post, options_for_select(my_helper(param_to_generate_option)), include_blank: "Select something"
```

Second edit:  You may need to play around with it, some of these options and tags don't mix-and-match.